# integral substitution that use the derivative

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I tried to solve the equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{k}{\sin{x}\sqrt{\sin^2{x}-k^2}}$$

and was suggested the substitution $$ \tan{u}=\frac{dy}{dx}\sin{x} $$

after some algebra (I'll add it if necessary) I get
$$ \frac{dy}{du} = \frac{\sin{u}}{\sqrt{\sin^2{u}-k^2}} $$

which is not hard to integrate using $ s = \cos{u}  $ and $du = -\csc{u}dt $

and then I get :
$$ -\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos{u}}{\sqrt{sin^2{u}-k^2}}\right) $$

but the answer should be with $x$ instead of $u$.

What should I do from here? Why can I make this substitution?

Comment: Just to be clear, I solved the integral - I'm just asking about this kind of substitution.